# elasticsearch - import csv using logstash date is not parsed as of datetime type

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to import csv into elasticsearch using logstash
I have tried using two ways:

1. Using CSV
2. Using grok filter

1) **For csv below is my logstash file:**

```
input {
  file {
    path => "path_to_my_csv.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
        separator => ","
        columns => ["col1","col2_datetime"]
  }
  mutate {convert => [ "col1", "float" ]}
  date {
        locale => "en"
        match => ["col2_datetime", "ISO8601"] // tried this one also - match => ["col2_datetime", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
        timezone => "Asia/Kolkata"
        target => "@timestamp" // tried this one also - target => "col2_datetime"
   }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
     hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
     index => "my_collection"

  }
  stdout {}
}
```

2) **Using grok filter:**

For grok filter below is my logstash file

```
input {
  file {
    path => "path_to_my_csv.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "(?<col1>(?:%{BASE10NUM})),(%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:col2_datetime})"}
    remove_field => [ "message" ]
  }
  date {
        match => ["col2_datetime", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
   }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
     hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
     index => "my_collection_grok"

  }
  stdout {}
}
```

**PROBLEM:**

So when I run both the files individually, I am able to import the data in elasticsearch. But my date field is not parsed as of datetime type rather it has been saved as string and because of that I am not able to run the date filters.

So can someone help me to figure out why it's happening.
My elasticsearch version is 5.4.1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share a few lines from your CSV file?

Comment: Please check this
1234365,2016-12-02 19:00:52

1234368,2016-12-02 15:02:02

1234369,2016-12-02 15:02:07

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 changes I made to your config file.

1) remove the under_score in the column name col2_datetime

2) add target

Here is how my config file look like...

```
vi logstash.conf

input {
  file {
    path => "/config-dir/path_to_my_csv.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
        separator => ","
        columns => ["col1","col2"]
  }
  mutate {convert => [ "col1", "float" ]}
  date {
        locale => "en"
        match => ["col2",  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
        target => "col2"
   }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
     hosts => "http://172.17.0.1:9200"
     index => "my_collection"

  }
  stdout {}
}
```

---

Here is the data file:

```
vi path_to_my_csv.csv

1234365,2016-12-02 19:00:52 
1234368,2016-12-02 15:02:02 
1234369,2016-12-02 15:02:07
```

Comment: it's still inserted as string

Comment: Logstash version? I tested it with 5.4 version.

Comment: mine is also the same

Comment: thanx it worked, I was checking in kibana with improper date filters